# Ionic can't run app on my device . says Angular dependency issue

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-cli

I did
npm install firebase angularfire2 --save
to install.

and then, whatever I do like ionic Cordova run android --device. ionic cordova platform update android… etc…
I can’t even remove android platform for this error.

has this error.

```
cordova platform add android --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.1.2

Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.1.2
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path /Users/jpd/Dropbox/pusher/node_modules/.bin/create
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /Users/jpd/Dropbox/pusher/node_modules/.bin/create: is outside /Users/jpd/Dropbox/pusher/node_modules/cordova-android and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/jpd/Dropbox/pusher/node_modules/.bin/create
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm
```

ERR! /Us`enter code here`ers/jpd/.npm/_logs/2018-03-12T02_11_58_513Z-debug.log

then I install one of those dependency
typing npm i --save @angular/common@^4.0.0 on terminal .
but has more error saying

npm WAR

```
N @angular/common@4.4.6 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@5.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@5.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@5.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@5.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@5.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

ionic info is as below.

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.2
Node       : v8.4.0
npm        : 5.6.0
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : not set
Misc:

backend : legacy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to install android@6.2.3 version.

**cordova platform add android@6.2.3**

And you could remove android folder when you can't remove android platform with **cordova platform rm android** command.

Comment: I deleted platform/android folder and npm module folder and re install by typing npm install . then it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is in your npm.**

> I completely uninstalled Nodejs and removed installed packages then
>   started again. my problem was solved but I will keep in mind your
>   solution for next time.